# Discord bot - issue saving a text file after hosting

Tags: python, heroku, discord

OK, I have been trying to think of a solution/find a solution myself for quite some time but everything I am attempting either ends up not a solution, or too complex for me to attempt without knowing it will work.

I have a discord bot, made in python. The bots purpose is to parse a blog for HTML links, when a new HTML link is posted, it will the post the link into discord.

I am using a textfile to save the latest link, and then parsing the website every 30seconds to check if a new link has been posted by comparing the link at position 0 in the array to the link in the textfile.

Now, I have managed to host my bot on Heroku with some success however I have since learned that Heroku cannot modify my textfile since it pulls the code from github, any changes are reverted after ~24hours.

Since learning this I have attempted to host the textfile on an AWS S3 bucket, however I have now learned that it can add and delete files, but not modify existing ones, and can only write new files from existing files on my system, meaning if I could do this, I wouldn't need to do this since I would be able to modify the file actually on my system and not need to host it anywhere.

I am looking for hopefully simple solutions/suggestions.

I am open to changing the hosting/whatever is needed, however I cannot pay for hosting.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

So, I am editing this because I have a working solution thanks to a suggestion commented below.

The solution is to get my python bot to commit the new file to github, and then use that commited file's content as the reference.

```
import base64
import os
from github import Github
from github import InputGitTreeElement

user = os.environ.get("GITHUB_USER")
password =  os.environ.get("GITHUB_PASSWORD")
g = Github(user,password)
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('YOUR REPO NAME HERE')
file_list = [
  'last_update.txt'
]

file_names = [
    'last_update.txt',
]

def git_commit():
    commit_message = 'News link update'
    master_ref = repo.get_git_ref('heads/master')
    master_sha = master_ref.object.sha
    base_tree = repo.get_git_tree(master_sha)
    element_list = list()

    for i, entry in enumerate(file_list):
        with open(entry) as input_file:
           data = input_file.read()

        if entry.endswith('.png'):
          data = base64.b64encode(data)

        element = InputGitTreeElement(file_names[i], '100644', 'blob', data)
        element_list.append(element)
    tree = repo.create_git_tree(element_list, base_tree)
    parent = repo.get_git_commit(master_sha)
    commit = repo.create_git_commit(commit_message, tree, [parent])
    master_ref.edit(commit.sha)
```

I then have a method called 'check_latest_link'  which checks my github repo's RAW format, and parses that HTML to source the contents and then assigns that content as a string to my variable 'last_saved_link'

```
import requests

def check_latest_link():
  res = requests.get('[YOUR GITHUB PAGE LINK - RAW FORMAT]')
  content = res.text
  return(content)
```

Then in my main method I have the follow :

```
@client.event
async def task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print('Running')
    while True:
      channel = discord.Object(id=channel_id)
      #parse_links() is a method to parse HTML links from a website
      news_links = parse_links()
      last_saved_link = check_latest_link()
      print('Running')
      await asyncio.sleep(5)
      #below compares the parsed HTML, to the saved reference, 
      #if they are not the same then there is a new link to post.
      if last_saved_link != news_links[0]:
        #the 3 methods below (read_file, delete_contents and save_to_file) 
        #are methods that simply do what they suggest to a text file specified elsewhere
        read_file()
        delete_contents()
        save_to_file(news_links[0])
        #then we have the git_commit previously shown.
        git_commit()
        #after git_commit, I was having an issue with the github reference
        #not updating for a few minutes, so the bot posts the message and 
        #then goes to sleep for 500 seconds, this stops the bot from 
        #posting duplicate messages. because this is an async function, 
        #it will not stop other async functions from executing. 
        await client.send_message(channel, news_links[0])
        await asyncio.sleep(500)
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to save it in a text file?

Comment: This was the only solution I could think of, it doesn't need to be saved in a text file, but if my bot ever goes down, it still needs to remember the very last update so it doesn't post the same link to anyones discord

Comment: What if you sync the html text file to github semifrequently so it doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: Can I do that from my bot itself? So my bot would take its latest file and upload it to github, so Heroku can then reference that file, which should change semi-frequently?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would work. You can run console commands by doing `import os` and `os.system("command")`

Comment: You would have to add the changes to git and then commit and push

Comment: I think the following commands will work:
`git add filename`
`git commit -m "update html"`
`git push -u origin master` Although you will need your git login to do this and if you can only put github code into this service that's a big security risk.

Comment: You could also use a database to store and retrieve the data. I use MongoDB and mLab for hosting it. Have a look at http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html if it may seem like a worthy solution

Comment: Hello, I have a working solution inspired by @Aeolus and have edited my question above to demonstrate, a DB was another solution I was going to look at but felt it was taking on a bit much at my current level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this so I can close the thread with an "Answer" - please refer to post edit.